# twitter bootstrap navbar collapse on my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I don't seem able to get navbar collapse to work on my rails app

application.html.erb is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? %>
  <title>Guidelines for Me</title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
function clearDefault(el) {
if (el.defaultValue==el.value) el.value = ""
}
function clearText(){
    search = $('.search-query');
    if (search.defaultValue==search.value)
    search.value = ""
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <% if Guideline.count % 100 ==0 %>
                <%= link_to "#{Guideline.count}" " guidelinesforme available - yay!", guidelines_path, :class => 'brand' %>
            <% else %>

                    <%= link_to "#{Guideline.count}" " guidelinesforme available!", guidelines_path, :class => 'brand' %>
            <% end %>


            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>


    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

            <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        List guidelines by...
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>


                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li><%= link_to "...Topic", topics_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "...Hospital", hospitals_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "...Specialty", specialties_path %></li>
                    </li>   
                </ul>

                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Favourites", favourites_path %></li>
                    <% else %>  
                    <li><%= link_to "Favourites", register_path %></li>
                    <% end %>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav pull-right">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <%= current_user.first_name %>
                    <% else %>
                    Log in or Sign up
                    <% end %>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <li ><%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_path %></li>
                        <li> <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %></li>
                        <li> <%= link_to "My additions", profiles_show_path(id: current_user.profile_name) %></li>
                    <% else %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", register_path %></li>
                    <% end %>

                    <li><%= link_to "About us", about_path %></li>
                </li>
                </ul>



                    <li class="nav pull-right">
                    <%= form_tag guidelines_path, :class => 'navbar-search pull-right', :onSubmit=>"clearText(this)",:method => :get do %>  

                    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'search-query input-small', :placeholder=>"Search", :ONFOCUS=>"clearDefault(this)" %> <% end %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
            <div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                <%= message %>
    </div>
        <% end %>


        <%= yield %>

    </div>
</body>

<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
</html>
```

in my application.js

```
$(".collapse").collapse()
```

I'm not using the bootstrap gem, I just added bootstrap manually.  I'm not sure if it's an issue with the plugin requirement or how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need add

```
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

at the end of the template

and

```
$(".collapse").collapse()
```

is inside of your_scripts.js not in your style.css file

Comment: sorry, that was a typo (now corrected).  It is in application.js. Regarding the <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script> - I thought all the plugins were in bootstrap.js which is included already from <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>?

Comment: ah ok.  bootstrap-dropdown.js seems to be included in my bootstrap.js. do I need to add it separately and if so am I just copying the text that's already in the bootstrap.js or is there somewhere else to get the bootstrap-dropdown.js from?

Comment: i think you have some problems with ul and li tags, maybe this cause the problems.
you need make this for parts until your done the ul lists. look this example of your code


<ul class="nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      List guidelines by...
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu"> <!-- here open a ul tag but no close-->
  </li>

Comment: Thanks but all the dropdown bits in the section you mentioned work fine.  I just want to add the navbar collapse part but that's what is not working

Comment: Yes your HTML markup is incorrect, you need to look at the responsive navbar here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar and address your HTML, if you need any help just let us know

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I have now sorted all the ul and li tags (edited above).  I still can't get the navbar collapse part to work (although the dropdowns are still working fine).  Any help on this?